# Non homogeneous Heat equation in polar coordinates with non homogeneous BC's

Tags: partial-differential-equations, polar-coordinates, heat-equation, sturm-liouville

I'm trying to work around my way of this problem

$$a\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}(r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r})+be^{-y(r-a)}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$$

$$\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right\rvert_{r=1}=-[bu+c]$$

$$u(a,t)=0$$
$$u(r,0)=1$$

I tried to use $u(r,t)=w(r,t)+v(r)$ but the thing is the only method that I know of to solve non homogeneous PDE involves doing separation of variables first, but I run into the problem of the non homogeneous BC. So I'm getting confused on how exactly to proceed, because I can try to solve the homogeneous PDE with $u(r,t)=w(r,t)+v(r)$, and get a solution, but how then should I proceed with the non homogeneous PDE? With other problems I'd try to express $f(r,t)$ with the functions that result from the separation of variables, in this case I can't proceed in the same way

Is there another method or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing nothing wrong. Write $u(r,t)=w(r,t)+v(r)$ and choose $v(r)$ as the solution to the ODE
$$
a\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dv}{dr}\right)+be^{-y(r-a)}=0 \tag{1}
$$
with boundary conditions
\begin{align}
v'(1)&=-bv(1)-c, \tag{2.1}\\
v(a)&=0. \tag{2.2}
\end{align}
With this choice, $w(r,t)$ will satisfy the homogeneous PDE
$$
a\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial w}{\partial r}\right)=\frac{\partial w}{\partial t} \tag{3}
$$
with the homogeneous boundary conditions
\begin{align}
w_r(1,t)&=-bw(1,t), \tag{4.1} \\
w(a,t)&=0, \tag{4.2} \\
\end{align}
and the modified initial condition
$$
w(r,0)=1-v(r). \tag{5}
$$
The problem for $w$ can be solved with the usual method of separation of variables.